# Perl: Batch POST Requests

Tags: perl, post, curl, request

I am making thousands of POST requests to my website. I am currently doing something like

```
my $exec = `curl -s "http://MYSITE" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: $ua" --data 'a=1&b=2&c=3'
```

I am currently using the `threads` module to run 20 threads at a time as this command needs to be ran thousands of times. Is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of just making system calls to cURL?

I know I can use `HTTP::Request` but I am not sure if this will make it run faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Net-Curl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Curl/) is a thin Perl interface to the `libcurl` library used by the `curl` utility.

Specifically, I think you'll be interested in the [Net::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Curl::Multi) module since it provides a means of submitting multiple requests simultaneously without involving threads or processes.

It is extremely fast<sup>[1]</sup>. It (like any other module) will make errors easier to handle.

---

1. It puts LWP to shame, even with a partial LWP-compatibility layer. It will obviously be faster than shelling out to access the same library.

Comment: I tried installing this but I keep getting error messages that curl/curl.h could not be found :( I was using Windows/Cygwin

Comment: You need libcurl including its dev files

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could use any of the numerous Perl modules that make HTTP request. Notable ones include: [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent), [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent), and [`HTTP::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny)(Core perl). The example below uses HTTP::Tiny:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use JSON;

my $ua = '...';
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->post(
   'http://example.com' => {
      content => to_json(
         { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 } 
      ),
      headers => { 
         'Accept-Language'           => 'en-US;en;q=0.8',
         'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => 1,
         'User-Agent'                => $ua,
      },
   },
);

unless ( $response->{is_success} ) {
   ...
}
```

Using any one of these modules will make dealing with errors easier.

Comment: Will this make a noticeable speed difference in comparison to curl?

Comment: I would assume not, since backticks have to create a subprocess before the curl command is executed. But, the only way to know for certain is to measure both.